# Why is linked text is overflowing the div box?

Tags: css, html, href

In chrome and safari, the links do not listen to the width:500px; in the css. The text does, but not the link.

[See print screen 1 here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2160796/1.0_links/Screen%20Shot%202012-11-29%20at%2013.41.13.png)

[See simple example here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2160796/1.0_links/Screen%20Shot%202012-11-29%20at%2014.00.49.png)

Any ideas?
Help much appreciated.
Thanks
Emma

I've tried a really simple test too. See code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#main {width:100px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main">Content for  id "main" Goes Here Content for  id "main" Goes Here Content for  id "main" Goes Here Content for  id "main" Goes Here <a href="http://www.thesun.co.uk/sol/homepage/showbiz/4672063/kristen-stewart-flashes-bra-award-bash-jim-jams.html">http://www.thesun.co.uk/sol/homepage/showbiz/4672063/kristen-stewart-flashes-bra-award-bash-jim-jams.html</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code:
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m8nRy/)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      #main {width:100px;}
      #main p{word-wrap: break-word;}
      #main a{word-wrap: break-word;}
    </style>
   </head>

   <body>
     <div id="main"><p>Content for  id "main" Goes Here Content for  id "main" Goes Here Content for  id "main" Goes Here Content for  id "main" Goes Here <a href="http://www.thesun.co.uk/sol/homepage/showbiz/4672063/kristen-stewart-flashes-bra-award-bash-jim-jams.html">http://www.thesun.co.uk/sol/homepage/showbiz/4672063/kristen-stewart-flashes-bra-award-bash-jim-jams.html</a></p>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>​
```

Comment: How does adding it in a paragraph help? Have you even tested this code? http://jsfiddle.net/BUyLj/

Comment: update answer with the correction and it works http://jsfiddle.net/m8nRy/ @StephanMuller

Answer (score 2):

It's because a link is usually seen as one single word (except when there's a hyphen in it, which is why your links eventually break at the filename).

One thing you could do is use the style `word-wrap: break-word` on the div, but that doesn't work in all browsers.